# Checkers multi-jump counting algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic

I'm doing my first C++ project in SFML - Checkers. 
Unfortunately I got stuck inventing a recursive function that would allow me to check every possible jumping combo and which would return me the coordinates.

How can I do that? I've searched a lot of webpages, didnt find the answer, 
so I assume it's easier than I think it is.

EDIT#1:

```
if (player2.isSelected(pos_x + blockSize, pos_y + blockSize))
    if (isBoardBlockEmpty(pos_x + 2 * blockSize, pos_y + 2 * blockSize))
        return true;
if (player2.isSelected(pos_x - blockSize, pos_y + blockSize))
    if (isBoardBlockEmpty(pos_x - 2 * blockSize, pos_y + 2 * blockSize))
        return true;
if (player2.isSelected(pos_x + blockSize, pos_y - blockSize))
    if (isBoardBlockEmpty(pos_x + 2 * blockSize, pos_y - 2 * blockSize))
        return true;
if (player2.isSelected(pos_x - blockSize, pos_y - blockSize))
    if (isBoardBlockEmpty(pos_x - 2 * blockSize, pos_y - 2 * blockSize))
        return true;
```

Comment: Do you already have code for a single jump?

Comment: @NicoSchertler 
Sure,
It checks if selected pawn's position + 1 block equals opponents pawn and if pawn's position +2 is free (the same code for every direction).
(I'll edit main post and paste it there)

Comment: One way to proceed would be to add the board state as an argument to that function. Then, modify the state based on the jump you are investigating (remove opponent, change position of own piece) and check again recursively from the target position.

Answer (score 2):

This is an instance of a tree search problem, where the nodes are boards and the edges between them are a specific pawn doing one jump at a time.

For a given board `board` and a pawn at position `pos`, you determine which jumps it can make:

- If there are no jumps possible, the multi-jump sequence ends. If the current jump list was not empty, report it as a sequence.
- If there are jumps possible, explore each of them recursively by making the jump (removing the jumped-over pawn from the board) and seeing if you can make more jumps from that position.

In pseudo-C++, this would look like the following. Note that this is written for educative purposes, without consideration for performance.

```
// Assuming types pos and board were defined earlier.
using jump_list = std::vector<pos>;

// List of moves from a given starting position and board
std::vector<pos> possible_jumps(pos start, const board& board);

// Apply a move (remove the pawn from the board, move the jumping pawn)
board apply_move(const board& board, pos start, pos move);

// I'm bundling the multi-jump calculation in a struct to easily store
// the resulting jump list.
struct multi_jump {
    std::vector<jump_list> jumps;
    multi_jump(pos start, board board) {
        explore({}, start, board);
    }

    void explore(jump_list so_far, pos start, board board) {
        auto moves = possible_jumps(start, board);
        if (moves.empty()) {
            if (!so_far.empty()) {
                jumps.push_back(so_far);
            }
        } else {
            for (const auto move : moves) {
                board new_board = apply_move(board, start, move);
                jump_list new_so_far = so_far;
                new_so_far.push_back(move);
                explore(new_so_far, move, new_board);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Finally, you can retrieve the list of jumps from a starting position and board as follows:

```
jump_list jumps = multi_jump(start, board).jumps;
```